# TransactionScope doesn't roll back while the nth insertion doesn't occur

Tags: c#, .net, transactions, transactionscope, distributed-transactions

I have a problem which make me turn around for 3 days.
I'm using transaction scope in this transactioscope I insert say 5 values in 5 tables. The insertion goes correctly for the first 3 tables and totally ignore the 4th insertion and insert the 5th value correctly without any problem. No exception appears and no rollback occurs.

EDIT: This problem only occurs on the production server and it's not regularly occur. In few times it occur and the most times it works correctly without any problems.

Note: this problem started to be appeared after i host another application on the same server.

```
public void InsertStuff()
{
    try
    {
        using(TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
        {
            //perform insert 1
            Tablel1.Insert();

            //perform insert 2
            Tablel2.Insert();

            //perform insert 3 - 
            Tablel3.Insert();

            //perform insert 4 - No insertion occur !!!!!
            Tablel4.Insert();

            //perform insert 5 - insertion works fine!!!!!
            Tablel5.Insert();


            ts.Complete();            
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: unlikely this can be answered as it stands.

Comment: [Have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) to swap last two table inserts? What's the result? Do you have any foreign keys in that tables?

Comment: I couldn't swap two tables because each one is related with the previous one .. i mean after insertion I get the record ID to be foreign key in the other table

Comment: Please use `throw;` to rethrow or better, do not add a `catch` if you are not doing anything. This way you are losing/hiding the stacktrace.

Comment: post the code in Tablel4.Insert();
, the problem is most likely in your insert code.

Answer (score 0):

If an exception does occur then the transaction scope should rollback.

Why don't you test your theory by throwing an exception yourself, or by explicitly calling a ts.Rollback() in the catch.

Comment: it doesn't go threw the catch because it does not feel that there was an error and the insertion does not occur..

Comment: that can't be right. So the insertion doesn't throw an exception, then it isn't an exception. Then what you can do, is to manually check that the inserts were succesful and if any of them failed call ts.Rollback() manually.

Comment: EDIT: this problem only occur on the production server and it's not regularly occur.. in few times it occur and the most times it works correctly without any problems ..

Note: this problem started to be appeared after i host another application on the same server.

Comment: you need to dig into the issue more. To see why the insert doesn't happen. If there was a problem inserting the data, then an exception would be thrown. Otherwise something else is wrong and you need to figure it out and complete your question with the missing details.

Answer (score 0):

It does not looks anything wrong with the transaction or program flow. Check whatever is programmed for

```
Tablel4.Insert();
```

There is something magical that program/computer will do by self. we often make mistakes  but do not notice. We can suggest the possibilities but its you who can double check your logic or post that code segment if want other to take a look.

Exception does not occur because the there could be a logical mistake instead some compilation or syntax